# How to check if date string contains hours/min/seconds part?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, momentjs

I have JS string with date: `21-05-2022`. It is also possible to receive date string as `21-05-2022T23:15:56Z` - date string with date and time data. I would like to check if incoming string contains only date or date and time. Now I am using a function which splits string by 'T' symbol and checks if resulted array has second [1] member. Maybe there is more elegant way to perform this operation? I can use `moment.js` library in this context.

Answer (score 4):

Alt variant:
`let isTimeHas = /:/.test(dateString)`

Answer (score 3):

since your date is always string, i would do : 
 `let result = dateString.includes('T');` if the string includes the T it means it is datetime